# ViewDataDictionary model is correct, failing when calling RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am porting a .NET MVC application to .NET Core. The issue is occurring when rendering a partial using `Html.RenderPartial`.

The relevant code is:

```
    <div class="row">
        <h2>@WebResources.OtherUsersSavedItems</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.OtherUsersSavedItems)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("SavedItem", Html.ViewDataDictionaryFrom(new { IsLink = true }, item));
        }
    </div>
```

The `OtherUsersSavedItems` property on the model is defined as `SavedItem[]`. There is an identical call to RenderPartial earlier in my view, which works, but the difference is that it's not using a custom ViewDataDictionary:

```
    <div class="row">
        <h2>@WebResources.SavedItems</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.SavedItems)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("SavedItem", item);
        }
    </div>
```

The code to ViewDataDictionaryFrom is as follows:

```
    public static ViewDataDictionary ViewDataDictionaryFrom(this IHtmlHelper helper, object dictionary, object model = null)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            return null;

        // Convert the object to a ViewDataDictionary
        ViewDataDictionary vdd = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary());
        foreach (var property in dictionary.GetType().GetProperties())
            vdd.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(dictionary));

        vdd.Model = model;

        return vdd;
    }
```

The previous code, when running under .NET MVC was using the `RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, Strink, Object, ViewDataDictionary)` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary%29) and that was working fine. There was one change between .NET MVC and .NET Core for the `ViewDataDictionaryFrom` method, which was to add the model and set it accordingly (`vdd.Model = model`) to try and work around the missing overload in .NET Core.

The exception I receive is `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MyApplication.Models.ListModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MyApplication.Models.SavedItem'.` Note that `ListModel` is the of the parent view.

The stack frames (truncated, starting at the line in my code which fails) is:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object
>   value)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary
>   source, object model, Type declaredModelType) lambda_method(Closure ,
>   ViewDataDictionary )
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.CreateViewDataDictionary(ViewContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(object
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__16.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__15.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__14.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper+d__60.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(IHtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, string partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   AspNetCore._Views_Index_cshtml+d__0.MoveNext()
>   in Index.cshtml
>                   Html.RenderPartial("SavedItem", Html.ViewDataDictionaryFrom(new { IsLink = true }, item));

Answer (score 1):

I went and looked at the source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e6c716444db33f63572ded447a760c7391b4bf79/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.cs). The overload

```
public static void RenderPartial(
        this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string partialViewName,
        ViewDataDictionary viewData)
```

Is a wrapper around `RenderPartialAsync` which invokes it with the current model, ignoring what is in the ViewDataDictionary that is passed in.

To correct my issue, I use the RenderPartialAsync method in my Razor view, which allows me to specify both the ViewDataDictionary and the model.